# How to use jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven and Eclipse. I need help generating Java classes from JSON Schema using jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin in Eclipse. :

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jsonschema2pojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.21</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/schema</sourceDirectory>
                    <targetPackage>com.airportcodes.model</targetPackage>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

Comment: Is there a question here? What's the problem? What are you observing that is different than what you expect? Details matter.

Comment: How do I generated java objects from json schema. I tried using maven build, but that did not generate any java classes.

Comment: The `pluginManagement` section of a pom.xml sets plugin configuration, but to actually invoke a plugin you need to add an `execution` of it into the `build` section of your pom.xml